# Update State, City dropdown base on Country Select Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, cascadingdropdown

I have this releationship.
One to Many Between Country to State.
One to Many Between State to City.

On Employment Form, I have to show these dropdown, i want when i select a country, only it's releated states are shown. Now it is showing all.

here is my form code.

```
<?php

namespace PNC\UsersBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;

class EmploymentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder ->add('designation', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Designation ',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => 'Designation Name',
                        'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid designation',
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    )))
                    ->add('organization', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Organization',
                    'attr' => array(
                    'required'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => 'Organization Name',
                    'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid organization',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    )))
                    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                        'label' => ucfirst('country'),
                        'class' => 'PNCGeneralBundle:Country',
                        'property'=>'name',
                        //'property_path'=>false, //Country is not directly related to City
                        'attr'=> array(
                            'required'    => true,
                            'invalid_message' => 'You selected an invalid Industry',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        )
                    ))
                    ->add('state', 'entity', array(
                        'label' => ucfirst('state'),
                        'class' => 'PNC\GeneralBundle\Entity\State',
                        'attr'=> array(
                            'required'    => true,
                            'invalid_message' => 'You selected an invalid Industry',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        )
                    ))
                    ->add('city', 'entity', array(
                        'label' => ucfirst('city'),
                        'class' => 'PNC\GeneralBundle\Entity\City',
                        'attr'=> array(
                            'required'    => true,
                            'invalid_message' => 'You selected an invalid Industry',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        )
                    ))
                    ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                        'attr' => array(
                            'label' => ucfirst('save'),
                            'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                        )
                    ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PNC\UsersBundle\Entity\Employments',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pncusers_bundle_employments_type';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please cut this down to size.  You can show the same problem with two countries with two states each and not include the cities (which will be the same idea).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the easiest way would be to show/hide options via JavaScript. Dump countries, states and cities as JSON and use that as source for decision making in JS.

Comment: Thats a neat way to achieve it